# angularjs working with bootstrap navbar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

I am trying to create a one-page website that loads views in based on buttons clicked on a bootstrap navbar.  However, The content of the page does not show up.  Can anyone tell me what is going wrong?

Okay, so I have this index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- define angular app -->
<html ng-app="scotchApp">

<head>
  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="controllers/userdetailsController.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="utils/basicUtils.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> User</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="main">

  <!-- angular templating -->
  <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
  <div ng-view></div>

</div>



</body>

</html>
```

This script.js:

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
    var scotchApp = angular.module('hyprPortal', ['ngRoute']);

    // configure our routes
    scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });
    });

     //create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
    scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
    });
```

And this home.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>User Details</title>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "../controllers/userdetailsController.js"></script>
    <script src = "../utils/basicUtils.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="hyprPortal" ng-controller="UserRegCtrl">
    <!--<form ng-submit = "add(USERID)">
        User ID:<br>
        <input type = "text" name = "USERID" ng-model = "USERID"><br>
        <input type = "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>-->
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>{{returnName}}</td>
            <td>{{AID}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need the `html`, `body`, and `script` tags inside `home.html`. You only need the content. All script tags should be defined in `index.html`.

Comment: I have created a plunker for you , hope this will help you. https://plnkr.co/edit/Bvo3LkVmGNGZWxF4M66m?p=preview

Comment: Got rid of all that, still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues with your code.

1: The home.html need not to have all the head, body, parts.
2: the module name should be scothApp and should only be present as ng-app = "scothApp" in the index.html
3: your route already tells that the controller for Home.html is mainController so you need not to add another cotroller using ng-controller= "UserRegCtrl" in the home.html.

check out this plunker based on your code.

https://plnkr.co/edit/Bvo3LkVmGNGZWxF4M66m?p=preview

```
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: what if I want the other controller instead?

Comment: change it in the route itself.   .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'home.html',
                controller  : 'otherController'
            })